# ASP.NET MVC Displaying Multiple Images from Database. How to- Efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, razor

I've got a .NET MVC app where I need to display a list of images with some text. The images and text are stored in the database in the same table, and returned in my simple model. What I haven't figured out is how to display all of these images without hitting the database again for every single image.

I see several examples, such as:

- [ASP.NET MVC: loading images from database and displaying their in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142492/asp-net-mvc-loading-images-from-database-and-displaying-their-in-view)
- [Problem with displaying image from DB using asp.net MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448150/problem-with-displaying-image-from-db-using-asp-net-mvc-2)

and others, but they all go back to the database for every image. That doesn't make sense, because there could be dozens of images, and I don't want to keep making single calls to the database when I already have the image data returned in my model.

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, (and also never worked with images stored in a DB before) and I think I am just missing something, and that it can't be this difficult. If anyone has solved this, I'd love to hear it, and I think others would too, based on the other questions already here.

Comment: are the images always all displayed?  if so then make one call and dump the results in to a collection then cycle through that collection for displaying on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hit the database multiple times. I once thought it was a clever idea to load the images together with the text in the cache and then invalidate the cache when they were served. I also had to generate random URLs to avoid different users invalidating each others cache. I thought it was so clever to reduce the number of DB queries.

I am now so ashamed by this "cleverness" and I don't tell anybody. Don't think about it unless you have actual performance problem.

It is important to implement client side caching by setting the appropriate headers. Images are better cached on the client than on the server because even if you cache on the server you still take the network transfer hit if you do not cache on the client.

Also hitting the database by primary key (I assume this is how you are going to retreive images) is not an expensive operation and unless the images are 2MB+ I wouldn't worry about transfer from the database to the web server either.

Edit: And I just told everybody about my shame :(

Comment: the +1 is for your shameful admission :)

Comment: Clever people learn from their mistakes. Wise people learn from other people's mistakes. Be wise!

Comment: Good judgment comes from experience, and experience comes from bad judgment - touche!!. have a good weekend!!

Comment: Thanks @Stilgar. As much as I still think there is a better way, it is true that I don't have a scaling problem yet, and it's a simple app, and not worth implementing caching yet. If I do get to that point, I can rethink it then, and maybe get the images out of the DB, or add the cache as others have suggested.

Comment: You can easily add cache later without changing the rest of the code. Just try to load the image from cache and if it is not there load it from the database. But it really is not worth it. The client-side cache is infinitely more important.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a cache of retrieved images, stored in a shared container (like the `Application`).

When users ask for a view containing images, you retrieve them and store in the cache.
Then come requests for images and you can just retrieve them from the memory, without hitting the database.

The exact implementation depends on your specific scenario, you can limit the number of images stored in the cache, make the cache drop data automatically after some time or even use another server container (`Session` for example).

Anyway - returning data retrieved earlier always involves some kind of caching at the server side and should not be especially difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at ASP.NET caching. You can fetch the images from the database once, and keep them in the cache. Subsequent requests will get them from the cache until it expires.

Comment: Depending on the load distribution and the number of items this could lead to cache polution which in turn will make the cache slower for everything else and will consume a lot of RAM. Of course if there are few images requested by many users this will be a good solution but if there are a lot of images requestes by a small number of users it will fail miserably.